# Preventing mongodb crashes

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb with the web server.

Recently, I observed that mongodb server crashed after "no space left" for journalling.

So, after some online help I could repair and restart the DB.

But, for production, I am worried now.

Is there a way in mongodb - when bound to one machine - to truncate the journal files and prealloc files to get truncated without restart of mongodb or any other manual intervention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The journal will be [3 x 1GB files by default](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-journal), so really you should just make sure that you have at least 3GB space for the journal when you are starting up.  You can use the [`smallfiles` option](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#smallfiles) to reduce that to 3 x 128MB (384MB) instead, however I would not recommend that for any system with significant volume.

Similarly you can turn off pre-allocation using the [`noprealloc` option](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#noprealloc) but again I would not recommend doing so due to the potential performance issues you can hit as a result.

Both of these options must be configured when the process starts, there is no way to (re)configure them after the fact.